how to prove the basic property of the Bochner integral in terms of the simple function?
Definition  A function $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{X}$ is called simple if it can be represented as
$$
f(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^k I_{E_i}(\omega) g_i
$$
for some finite $k, E_i \in \mathscr{B}$ and $g_i \in \mathbb{X}$.
Definition  Any simple function $f(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^k I_{E_i}(\omega) g_i$ with $\mu\left(E_i\right)<\infty$ for all $i$ is said to be integrable and its Bochner integral is defined as (*):
$$
\int_E f d \mu=\sum_{i=1}^k \mu\left(E_i\right) g_i
$$
It is not difficult to verify that this definition does not depend on the particular representation of $f$. In particular, the $E_i$ can be chosen without loss to be disjoint. To see this merely observe that if any two sets $E_i$ and $E_j$ in a simple function overlap, which part of the function can be rewritten in an equivalent form using disjoint sets as
$$
g_i I_{E_i \cap E_j^c}(\omega)+g_j I_{E_j \cap E_i^c}(\omega)+\left(g_i+g_j\right) I_{E_i \cap E_j}(\omega)
$$
with $A^C$ indicating the complement of the set $A$.
The previous definition is extended to a general measurable function from $E$ to $\mathbb{X}$ as follows.
Definition  A measurable function $f$ is said to be Bochner integrable if there exists a sequence $\left\{f_n\right\}$ of simple and Bochner integrable functions such that
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E\left\|f_n-f\right\| d \mu=0
$$
In this case, the Bochner integral off is defined as
$$
\int_E f d \mu=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E f_n d \mu
$$
To see that this definition has merit first observe from (*) and the triangle inequality that
$$
\left\|\int_E f d \mu\right\| \leq \int_E\|f\| d \mu
$$
for any simple function $f$.
Question: how to prove that $$
\left\|\int_E f d \mu\right\| \leq \int_E\|f\| d \mu
$$
My attempt:

First, recall the definition of a simple function:
$f(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^k I_{E_i}(\omega) g_i$

By Definition, the Bochner integral of this simple function is:
$\int_E f d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^k \mu(E_i) g_i$

Now, let's apply the norm to both sides:
$\left\|\int_E f d\mu\right\| = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^k \mu(E_i) g_i\right\|$

By the triangle inequality, we know that the norm of a sum is less than or equal to the sum of the norms:
$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^k \mu(E_i) g_i\right\| \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \|\mu(E_i) g_i\|$

Since $\mu(E_i)$ is a non-negative scalar, we can take it out of the norm:
$\sum_{i=1}^k \|\mu(E_i) g_i\| = \sum_{i=1}^k \mu(E_i) \|g_i\|$

Now, observe that $\|f(\omega)\| = \|\sum_{i=1}^k I_{E_i}(\omega) g_i\| \leq \sum_{i=1}^k I_{E_i}(\omega) \|g_i\|$


I am stuck here.

Point 6 you can use the assumption that the $E_i$'s are disjoint. Thus you'd get an equality instead of an inequality.

Note that $| \int f_n | \le \int |f_n |$.

As you and the comments said, the inequality is trivial for simple functions (taking disjoint $E_i$'s), so for such a sequence $f_n$ we have
$$ ||\int f_n\text d\mu||\leq \int ||f_n||\text d \mu.$$ Now by definition $\int f_n\text d\mu\rightarrow \int f\text d\mu$, so the left side converges to $||\int f\text d\mu||$. Moreover $\left|||f||-||f_n||\right|\leq||f-f_n||$, so
$$\left|\int ||f_n||\text d\mu-\int ||f||\text d\mu\right|=\left|\int (||f_n||-||f||)\text d\mu\right|\leq \int \left|||f_n||-||f||\right|\text d\mu\leq \int ||f_n-f||\text d\mu\rightarrow 0,$$
so the right side converges to $\int ||f||\text d\mu$ and the inequality is proved.
Note that this inequality (for simple functions) is needed to prove that the Bochner integral is well-defined in the first place.

Thanks! I have another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4972240/ask-the-proof-for-bounded-and-finite-dimensional-implies-totally-bounded
Could you help me?
